# Vb. net split container with expand/collapse button

Tags: vb.net, splitter, splitcontainer

I have 2 panels created using split container, my question is how can I add an expand/collapse button inside the splitter of split container?

I also tried dotnetbar splitter but it doesn't have a property for adding expand/collapse button.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by Expand/Collapse ? What is it you want to achieve ?

Comment: To my knowledge, you cannot add controls to the splitter bar of a split container. You will need to draw one on it yourself by overriding the onPaint method or create your own control.